# Regex help, need alphanumeric, spaces and ' - ,

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am currently using

```
var rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
```

I would like to know how I can allow `'` as well. For example it currently allows `assassin` but not `assassin's`

What do I need to change?

Comment: var rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -']"); or var rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -\']");

Comment: Thanks @jeff worked a treat

Comment: @jeff, no that's wrong, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'` needs to come before the `-`:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 '-]
```

Otherwise you've just specified a range of chars between (space) and `'`

Comment: What is the difference between your solution and Jeff's they seem very similar. Thanks for you help.

Comment: [ -'] is a range. In other words any char between (space) and `'`. Do you see it? `!` for example would be accepted